# motion tracking (or position tracking) with tilting

Tags: sensors

I'm looking for a sensor or a tool for tracking motion on a surface similar to Ultrasound probe, for a relatively small movement, about less than 30cm, and it needs to be able to tilt.
standard computer mouse for example would work fine if I didn't need to tilt and move simuletanousely.
I know it can be done with accelerometer, but according to what I've read it is not practically useful (maybe it's outdated).

Comment: A wacom tablet and a holder for the pen so you can move it like a mouse. Or just slap a gyroscopic sensor on the mouse.

Comment: what do you mean by "tilt"? would something like a touchpad work?

Comment: Any smart phone.

Comment: @StainlessSteelRat does the smartphone accelerometer sensors would give me a reliable deltas of movement?

Comment: @joojaa, I've edited my question

Comment: Accelerometers position data drift over time, but nothing the phone canera cant compensate for.

Comment: @joojaa Do you have a code that implements this or an app?

Comment: You have 3d accelerometer and 3d magnetic field tilt orientation.   I don't know your application, but I'd go that way or at least investigate it.